# Problems getting values into a dynamic variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

selectedsong div has differents links with differents rel=""... and the problems is...

I'm using that:

```
selectedBtn = $('#selectedsong a');
selectedBtn.click(function()
{
    self.selectedsong($(this).attr('rel'));
    return false;
});

selectedsong: function(number)
{
    $('#selectedsong').html('new content with new links, rel, and more...');
    selectedBtn = $('#selectedsong a'); <---- THE PROBLEM IS HERE,
}
```

The problem is that, in the first click it works properly, but when the #selectedsong content change, selectedBtn = $('#selectedsong a'); don't work properly, because the selectedBtn.click(function() doesn't work :'(

Thank you very much!

Comment: You need to use `.on` http://api.jquery.com/on/ since you are modifying the `.innerHTML`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
$('#selectedsong').on('click','a',function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent default behavior of anchor click

    self.selectedsong($(this).attr('rel'));

    //return false;  dont use return false as it does more work than you need
});
selectedsong: function(number) 
{
  $('#selectedsong').html('new content with new links, rel, and more...');

}
```

As your HTML content changes you need to use event delegation.

read more on [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you changed the html inside `#selectedsong`, and that removed your `<a>` tag from it, and that's what you're trying to do a select on, is the `<a>` tag inside `#selectedsong`. Maybe you could try and just select `#selectedsong` instead of the anchor tag? Or when you change the html, change the html of `#selectedsong a`.